# JUL log messages and Apache log4j2 log4j-jul logging as org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger

Tags: java, log4j2, java.util.logging, apache-commons-logging

I have an application using `log4j2` with `tomcat-jdbc`. The `tomcat-jdbc` classes all log using `java.util.logging (JUL)`, so I looked it up and saw I could route all `JUL` log calls to `log4j2` with the following dependency and JVM parameter:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the JVM parameter `-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager`.

Overall, my maven logging config is:

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <log4j.version>2.3</log4j.version>
    <oracle.ojdbc.version>11.2.0</oracle.ojdbc.version>
    <spring.framework.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Logging using log4j 2.x -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- snipped non log4j related dependencies -->
<dependencies>
```

When I run the app, I get messages from tomcat-jdbc in my log4j2 logs now, but I can't tell where they are coming from because the LogManager from log4j-jul is overwriting that information:

```
2015/10/13 08:00:23.358 DEBUG 20512[main] org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger log:99 - Executing prepared SQL query
2015/10/13 08:00:23.360 DEBUG 20512[main] org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger log:99 - Executing prepared SQL statement [...]
2015/10/13 08:00:23.362 DEBUG 20512[main] org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger log:99 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2015/10/13 08:00:23.415 DEBUG 20512[main] org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger log:99 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

How can I get the information from the original message placed in the log?

I know `Log4perl` had a variable you could adjust if you were intercepting an event (via signal handler, etc): `$Log::Log4perl::caller_depth++;`, which would facilitate this. Not necessarily sure if this would be helpful though, since the code that re-routes the logging is done from a 3rd party library (org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-jul)...

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you raise this issue on the log4j2 issue tracker (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2 ).

Comment: @Remko Popma: is that all this boils down to? Is there no other way to convert JUL to Log4j2? I'm open to trying other methods, if they are available...

Comment: I think the problem is that in your case the Log4j2 logger is wrapped twice: one by the JUL logger, and again by the apache commons logging Logger. This will require special treatment...